# How to print lists in a dictionary horizontally in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

Hello I'm working on an ASCII banner which either prints a dictionary of list that makes an Asterisk alphabet. So far, I succeeded in printing it vertically, But i'm having trouble printing it horizontally.

Would anyone please help me?

This is what I have so far.

My approach to printing horizontally was concatenation assignment that prints all the first element of the list and then printing out the second.

But seems like my logic is flawed since when i put it in a nested loop it concatenates even more to the first line

```
letter_dict = {'A':
["***** ",
"*   * ",
"***** ",
"*   * ",
"*   * "],
'B':["***   ",
     "*   * ",
     "****  ",
     "*   * ",
     "****  "],
'C':["***** ",
     "*     ",
     "*     ",
     "*     ",
     "***** "],
'D':["****  ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "****  "],
'E':["***** ",
     "*     ",
     "***** ",
     "*     ",
     "***** "],
'F':["***** ",
     "*     ",
     "***** ",
     "*     ",
     "*     "],
'G':["***** ",
     "*     ",
     "* *** ",
     "* * * ",
     "***** "],
'H':["*     ",
     "*     ",
     "***** ",
     "*     ",
     "*     "],
'I':["***** ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   ",
     "***** "],
'J':["***** ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   ",
     "***   "],
'K':["*   * ",
     "*  *  ",
     "* *   ",
     "*  *  ",
     "*   * "],
'L':["*     ",
     "*     ",
     "*     ",
     "*     ",
     "***** "],
'M':["*   * ",
     "* * * ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * "],
'N':["*     ",
     "**    ",
     "* *   ",
     "*  *  ",
     "*   * "],
'O':["***** ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "***** "],
'P':["***** ",
     "*   * ",
     "***** ",
     "*     ",
     "*     "],
'O':["***** ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "* **  ",
     "*** * "],
'R':["***** ",
     "*   * ",
     "***** ",
     "*  *  ",
     "*   * "],
'S':["***** ",
     "*     ",
     "***** ",
     "    * ",
     "***** "],
'T':["***** ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   "],
'U':["*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "***** "],
'V':["*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     " * *  ",
     "  *   "],
'W':["*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "*   * ",
     "* * * ",
     " * *  "],
'X':["*   * ",
     " * *  ",
     "  *   ",
     " * *  ",
     "*   * "],
'X':["*   * ",
     " * *  ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   ",
     "  *   "],
'Z':["***** ",
     "   *  ",
     "  *   ",
     " *    ",
     "***** "]}


def print_banner(str_input, horizontal):

    str_input = str_input.upper()

    if horizontal != True:
        for i in range(len(str_input)):
            for j in range(6):
                print(letter_dict[str_input[i]][j])

    else:
        horizontal_line = ""


        for m in range(len(str_input)):

            horizontal_line += letter_dict[str_input[m]][0]

        print(horizontal_line)

print_banner("ABCD", True)
```

Comment: If you're on Unix/Linux, why not just use a 'banner' call for this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. You need to compose the whole line line-by-line, like a dot-matrix printer:

```
else:
     for line in range(5):               # Each letter is 5 lines high
          for m in str_input:           
               horizontal_line += letter_dict[m][line]
          horizontal_line += "\n"
     print(horizontal_line)
```

Example run:

```
In [7]: str_input = "BAR"

In [8]: horizontal_line = ""

In [9]: %paste
     for line in range(5):               # Each letter is 5 lines high
          for m in str_input:
               horizontal_line += letter_dict[m][line]
          horizontal_line += "\n"
     print(horizontal_line)

***   ***** *****
*   * *   * *   *
****  ***** *****
*   * *   * *  *
****  *   * *   *
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it has the same problem with my initial code. in the nested loop, the ascii list for the first line iterated 5 times and then the second line is iterated five times. Or at least that's what i think is going on

Comment: Okay, I got it working as well. I overlooked the horizontal_line += "\n". Do you think you can explain to me what that does?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` to make the operation a little cleaner:

```
for line in zip(letter_dict['L'],letter_dict['O'],letter_dict['L']):
    print(*line)

*      *****  *     
*      *   *  *     
*      *   *  *     
*      *   *  *     
*****  *****  *****
```

Note that you've got an error in your above `letter_dict`, you assign 'Q' over what you had in 'O'.  And I believe your 'H' is malformed.